# Trouble transfering Microsoft Office 2019 to new computer

Tags: microsoft-office

I just bought a new computer and would like to transfer MS Office 2019 from the old one.  I've searched online and everything says to log into my Microsoft account. But when I do that it says it can't find any subscriptions under that account. I don't recall how I purchased Office, don't have the product key, and don't know what other account I could've used with Microsoft. Any ideas for how to resolve this (other than buying a new license)?

Comment: Office 2019 is a perpetual license so there has to be a license key.  While you can log into a Microsoft Account to take advantage Office features that have synergy with OneDrive it’s not required.  Without a license key you won’t be able to install Office 2019 on the new system.  If you had a Office 365 subscription, and logged into your Microsoft Account within Office 365, you do get the added benefits of getting Office 365 specific features (since that will effectively upgrade your installation to the current Office 365 build)

Comment: The second Office 365 in my last comment was supposed to be Office 2019, logging into a Microsoft Account with an active Office 365 license, upgrades that installation to Office 365. Office 2019 is a specific build of Office 365, plus relative security updates, which is the reason the build for Office 2019 still changes monthly still. Essentially the feature set is locked in time with Office 2019, to a specific point in time, based off the Office 365 baseline. Office 2022 will be no different, whatever the baseline is at that time, will be the feature set. Office 365 will receive new features.

Answer (score 0):

Can the old computer be turned on? Then, is Office 2019 still on it?

1. If yes， please open one Office app, go to File > Account, check the version name of Office 2019，and check whether there is "Belong to" XXXXX@XXXX.XXX".
2. If not, is there any stickers denoting pre-installed Office 2019 on the old machine?

For the free pre-installed Office, if you lost the key or forget the account,
please find the valid proof of machine purchase, then try to [contact Microsoft
support for assistance](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/).

Besides, recall mailbox that you have registered, searched the mail records, check
whether you have received any mail from Microsoft, then check whether there is any
information about the redemption key and the binding account.

You may also refer to this article "[You forgot your Microsoft account username](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/you-forgot-your-microsoft-account-username-b2049472-3b8f-27d3-61c6-67a668453f4c)".

Comment: COA for Office 2019 wouldn't appear on the device itself.  Microsoft stop printing the license key on COA stickers that are placed on physical devices when Windows 8 was released.  The stickers are used for retail editions of their products.